# java code for deadlock situation?

Tags: java

here is the code

```
public class TestDeadlockExample1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {  
            final String resource1 = "xyz";  
            final String resource2 = "pqr";  
            // t1 tries to lock resource1 then resource2  
            Thread t1 = new Thread() {  
              public void run() {  
                  synchronized (resource1) {  
                   System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");  

                   try { Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (Exception e) {}  

                   synchronized (resource2) {  
                    System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");  
                   }  
                 }  
              }  
            };  

            // t2 tries to lock resource2 then resource1  
            Thread t2 = new Thread() {  
              public void run() {  
                synchronized (resource2) {  
                  System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");  

                  try { Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (Exception e) {}  

                  synchronized (resource1) {  
                    System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 1");  
                  }  
                }  
              }  
            };  


            t1.start();  
            t2.start();  
            System.out.println("completed");
          }  
}


here 

 t1.start();  
 t2.start();  
 System.out.println("completed");
```

here

in this t1.start() and t2.start() are written in sequential order, so my doubt is that both the thread starts at the same or not
or t1 starts, executes then comes to t2 and executes, if this is correct, how this becomes a deadlock situation..i want to know the execution of these threads

Comment: Why do you lock in the same order resources ?

Comment: actually i was looking for deadlock situation ,,and i ended up with this code..but the execution i didn't understand

Answer (score 1):

When you launch your java program, JRE spawns main thread and that main thread executes your `main` method.

When you call `t1.start()`, new thread spawns and executes first anonymous class's `run` method. From this point there are 2 threads executing simultaneously in your program: "main thread" and "thread 1".

When you call `t2.start()`, another thread spawns and executes second anonymous class's `run` method. From this point there are 3 threads executing simultaneously in your program: "main thread", "thread 1", "thread 2".

The order in which threads are executing is not defined. It could be anything. Generally they are executing simultaneously.

Your "thread 1" and "thread 2" acquire locks on `resource1` and `resource2` correspondingly and sleep for 10 seconds. While that happens, your "main" thread finishes its execution. But there are 2 more threads in your program, so while `main` method finished, program is not finished yet.

After sleeping your "thread 1" and "thread 2" trying to acquire locks on `resource 2` and `resource 1`, but those locks are already acquired so they will wait until lock holder will release it. Lock holder will never release it, as it waits for other resource so this program will never stop. That's classic deadlock situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that to prevent deadlocks, you need to make the `synchronized` block be consistently the same.

```
          public void run() {  
              synchronized (resource1) {  
              synchronized (resource2) {  
               System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");  
               System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");  
               try { Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (Exception e) {}  
               }  
             }  
          }
```

and

```
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {  
          public void run() {  
            synchronized (resource1) {  
            synchronized (resource2) {  
              System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");  
              System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 1");  
              try { Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (Exception e) {}  
              }  
            }  
          }  
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

> in this t1.start() and t2.start() are written in sequential order, so
>   my doubt is that both the thread starts at the same or not or t1
>   starts, executes then comes to t2 and executes

A call to `start()` doesn't ensure that a Thread starts *immediately*. A native call is made via `start0()` which inturn calls the OS to fork a thread. So, basically, thread2 can start before thread1. You have no control over which thread starts first.

> how this becomes a deadlock situation

There is a probability of *deadlock* here because `t1` might get lock on `resource1` and `t2` might get lock on `resource2` at the same time. Now, both threads want the resource held by the other thread. Hence you have a deadlock.

So as a standard practice, both `t1` and `t2` should acquire lock in the *same sequence*.

Comment: so we cannot predict that which thread going to be started, may be t2 starts and t1 starts later or t1 starts and t2 starts later or both starts at the same time..but if the sleep time is too short i mean sleep(1); then the resource may get free and avoid the dead lock situation ..so we cannot confirm that this code goes to deadlock situation every time..

Comment: @vineeth.soman - We cannot confirm deadlock situations will happen. OS has deadlock prevention and resolution mechanisms. To add to this `sleep(1)` is very small on modern computers. It might actually be ignored. Yes, we cannot predict which thread starts first.. Also, it is not guaranteed that the thread that starts first will get the lock first :P..

Answer (score 0):

sleep() guarantees that both t1 and t2 acquire their first lock before they proceed to their second lock. No matter which thread runs first.

Comment: I think the *length* for which the thread *sleeps* is important here. In his current code `sleep(10000)` is sufficient to ensure the behavior you mentioned but if the sleep duration is shorter, one thread might acquire both locks first

Answer (score 0):

***"so my doubt is that both the thread starts at the same or not or t1 starts, executes then comes to t2 and executes"***

Simply because the threads t1 and t2 are spawned sequentially, does not imply that they execute sequentially. Threads are used for parallel execution of units of work.

Due to the sleep method calls in your code, it will deadlock because

1. t1 acquires R1 or t2 acquires t2. The order is indeterminate
2. Both threads  sleep for 10 seconds after acquiring their respective resource, so we can be say with high degree of certainty in this example  that both threads have acquired the resources at some point during the sleep period of the other.
3. When t1 or t2 wake up and try to acquire the second resource, which is already held by the respective threads sibling it will block. Both threads will block attempting to acquire the resource held by the other.

This scenario only occurs because the threads are executing in parallel, not sequentially.

Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html

Answer (score 0):

The order of thread execution is not defined.

There is a high risk for your program  to go to deadlock. But you can slightly change the order of lock in the second thread to avoid deadlock. I've modified and given below. Again this depends on the logic you are going to write.

```
Thread t2 = new Thread() {  
  public void run() {  
    synchronized (resource1) {  
      System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");  

      try { Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (Exception e) {}  
      System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for resource 1...");
      synchronized (resource2) {  
        System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 1 and 2");  
      }  
    }  
  }  
};
```